# What is DbxRequestConfig?

Tags: java, dropbox-api

Hey everyone I was doing the dropbox tutorial and I just wondered what

```
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig(
            "JavaTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
```

means.

Comment: Did you try Googling it? http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.6.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxRequestConfig.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbxRequestConfig javadoc :

A grouping of a few configuration parameters for how we should make requests to the Dropbox servers.

http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.6.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxRequestConfig.html